# Adding a second nvme drive

Tags: mount, gparted

I have just installed a second NVME drive to my laptop and cannot get it to work properly.

I am new to Ubuntu (Linux) and am struggling with the advice on the following tutorial -

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

I have used Gparted to create a single partition from this second drive and can 'see' it within the file manager (Dolphin). I get an 'access denied message when I try to place a file within it however.

Gparted gives the following information about this second drive

- List item
- File system: ext4
- UUID: 36372849-0d3c-40d9-b3b4-dae1139c10f0
- Mounted on: Mounted on /media/bob9395/36372849-0d3c-40d9-b3b4-dae1139c10f0
- Path: /dev/nvme1n1p1

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance, Bob

Answer (score 2):

> I get an 'access denied message when I try to place a file within it however.

The correct order is:

- Format the partition and set a mountpoint. "Path: /dev/nvme1n1p1" is not the mountpoint, it is an actual name you provided at the formatting settings.
- Optional: add the device to /etc/fstab. Otherwise you will need to mount it manually
- Change the user and owner. from command line:

  ```
  sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mountpoint
  ```

The last one is to make you the owner. If you have more users change the 2nd $USER to the group those users belong to.

Comment: Thank you for the very prompt reply Rinzwind; it is very much appreciated!!I will try that when I get back home

Comment: I also like to set permissions & use links to data folders in a data partition to have that data directly in /home. See this for a bit more detail: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Comment: Why is  */dev/nvme1n1p1* mounted on `/media`. That mountpoint is usually where external drives are found?

Comment: I have now idea how it mounted on /media (prob a result of me thrashing about on Konsole) but I have deleted it now and trying to follow the above advice. Thanks for your patience everyone .. very much appreciated. Bob